# Buddypress change sender from notification mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email, buddypress

Buddypress is sending a notification mail ( for example when i receive a private message ).

The sender is Root User and the email address is root@localhost.

is there a way to overwrite the sender name and its email adress without make some changes in a core file?

if found this but its not working for me

```
add_action( 'bp_email', function( $email_type, $email_obj ) {
 $email_obj->set_from( "Greensheet@localhost", "Greensheet" );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Wordpress 4.5.2
Buddypress 2.5.2

regards

Comment: this is email address Greensheet@localhost?

Comment: i want to change it from root@localhost to greenshet@localhost

Comment: have you placed that code in function.php?

Comment: Maybe you should use a valid email address, like `greensheet@localhost.com`

Comment: the email adress does not matter. it works when i edit line 73 and 79in wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php and change the root entry to the one i like.. but i guess this will be lost after a new version comes out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this filter 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );

```
function my_mail_from( $email )
{
    return "noreply@yourdomain.com";
}
```

Add this code in your functions.php or create your site plugin